# Slow ethernet connection on Fedora

Tags: linux, fedora, ethernet, kde-plasma-workspace

I am currently working on **Fedora 30** on my laptop. I use **KDE Plasma** as a working station (not sure of the term). I reinstalled Fedora and Windows (as dual boot) not so long ago, and since I reinstalled it, **my ethernet connection is very slow** whereas my wifi connection work very well. I checked on Windows and my ethernet worked very well, it only slow down on Fedora. To try to fix this I followed many stuff on the internet and follow many stuff here, but it all lead to a dead-end...

So here I am, asking for your help, maybe I did a bad configuration of ethernet on fedora ? I don t know... I am sorry if it is obvious as hell, I am not a big head of linux... If there is any info that you need to help me better, just ask ! I will try to fetch it right away ! (and sorry for the english, doing my best !). Have a nice day !

Here are some edit to give more info (thanks to the advice of rickhg12hs):
lspci -k give me that:

```
 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation Ethernet Connection (6) I219-LM (rev 30)
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device 2279
    Kernel driver in use: e1000e
    Kernel modules: e1000e
```

and this is what journalctl -g Ethernet gives me: [a screenshot of the result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eAiPf.png)

Also to know how fast I am with my connection: I use [Speed test](https://www.speedtest.net/) and [Nperf](https://www.nperf.com/fr/) and also I know something is mess-up because I can download only at max 20KB/s (wheras for the same file I would have had a faster download)

Here is what `journalctl -g enp0s31f6` shows (a lot of stuff):

1)

```
Apr 16 13:12:45 Galahad org.fedoraproject.Anaconda.Modules.Network[1548]: DEBUG:anaconda.modules.network.device_configuration:added NetworkDeviceConfiguration(connection_uuid='a852f5e6-fb52-3eae-b5cb-17fa991d9d71', device_name='enp0s31f6', device_type=<enum NM_DEVICE_TYPE_ETHERNET of type NM.DeviceType>)
Apr 16 13:12:45 Galahad org.fedoraproject.Anaconda.Modules.Network[1548]: DEBUG:anaconda.modules.network.network:Device configurations changed: [(NetworkDeviceConfiguration(connection_uuid='', device_name='', device_type=0), NetworkDeviceConfiguration(connection_uuid='a852f5e6-fb52-3eae-b5cb-17fa991d9d71', device_n>
Apr 16 13:12:45 Galahad org.fedoraproject.Anaconda.Modules.Network[1548]: DEBUG:anaconda.modules.network.device_configuration:add_connection: not adding a852f5e6-fb52-3eae-b5cb-17fa991d9d71: already existing: [NetworkDeviceConfiguration(connection_uuid='a852f5e6-fb52-3eae-b5cb-17fa991d9d71', device_name='enp0s31f6'>
Apr 16 13:12:45 Galahad org.fedoraproject.Anaconda.Modules.Network[1548]: DEBUG:anaconda.modules.network.network:Device configurations created: [NetworkDeviceConfiguration(connection_uuid='a852f5e6-fb52-3eae-b5cb-17fa991d9d71', device_name='enp0s31f6', device_type=<enum NM_DEVICE_TYPE_ETHERNET of type NM.DeviceType>
```

2)

```
Apr 16 13:30:26 Galahad kernel: TCP: enp0s31f6: Driver has suspect GRO implementation, TCP performance may be compromised.
```

3)

```
Apr 17 21:56:14 Galahad kdeinit5[8557]: kf5.kio.core: "The file or folder ../devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.6/net/enp0s31f6 does not exist."
Apr 17 21:59:04 Galahad kdeinit5[9020]: kf5.kio.core: "The file or folder ../devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.6/net/enp0s31f6 does not exist."
Apr 17 21:59:17 Galahad kdeinit5[9027]: kf5.kio.core: "The file or folder ../devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.6/net/enp0s31f6 does not exist."
```

There is like 5 times the Number 2, I think this is the main source of my issue, does any one of you knows what could have done that and how to fix this ?

Comment: If it works fine in Windows but not in Fedora, then it's likely a driver issue.

Comment: how could I check that ?

Comment: Assuming your Ethernet device is on the PCI bus, you can find all the kernel modules in use with `lspci -k`.  You may also be able to find the connection speed in your kernel message logs.  For example, does `journalctl -g YourEthernetDeviceNameGoesHere` show your some useful information.  Or perhaps you could also find some information with `journalctl -g YourEthernetKernelModuleNameGoesHere`.  Editing your original question above with new information would be helpful to potential responders.  Describing how you perform your speed tests would also be helpful.

Comment: What does `journalctl -g enp0s31f6` show?

Comment: This is an interesting thread.  https://lkml.org/lkml/2019/5/28/703  Related?  I'm not sure.

Comment: What does `ethtool -i enp0s31f6` show?  What does `ethtool -k enp0s31f6` show?  `sudo` may be necessary for those commands.

Comment: Given the number of questions/threads about poor Ethernet performance in recent Linux distros, be it Fedora, Debian, Arch, Kali, etc... I'm beginning to wonder if it's not a kernel problem. I know it's difficult, if not downright impossible, sometimes, to downgrade your kernel to a previous branch, but there seems to be many issues with the 5.x branch of late. Have you tried to run a live edition of a previous Fedora version, one based on a 4.x kernel, just to make sure it's indeed a driver issue, as the others suggested (and there's a good chance they're right, mind you)?

Comment: Hello Didier ! I am pretty sure that (in my case) it is not a kernel problem, because I installed Fedora trough an usb key that my school gave to me, and I reinstalled it with the same key... Before my reinstallation of fedora, mu previous fedora worked well with the Ethernet... So I think that if there is an error it must have been during the installation. But anyway thanks ! And thanks to everyone who have been trying to help me ! You are all a bunch of nice people !